# Debugging dockerized Django in VS Code results in error "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect"

Tags: python, django, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want to debug my Django application using a docker container in Visual Studio Code.

Microsoft published a guide how to do that, which I followed step by step:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python

But when I try to run the debugger, I get the following error message:

```
Timed out waiting for launcher to connect
```

---

Here is what I did step by step:

1. I initialized a simple Django application using `django-admin startproject helloworld`
2. In VS Code I opened the folder including the `manage.py`
3. Opened Command Palette `Ctrl + Shift + P`, and then selected `Docker: Add Docker Files to Workspace...`
4. Select Application Platform `Python: Django`
5. Include Docker Compose files `No`
6. Relative path to the app's entrypoint `manage.py`
7. What ports does your app listen on? `8000`

VS Codes then creates several files (see below).

---

When I try to start the debugger (like in the guide), I get the following error message:

[image: Docker: Python - Django]
[image: Error: Timed out waiting for launcher to connect]

The terminal doesn't show any error messages, but the commands executed:
[image: terminal 1]

[image: terminal 2]

---

.vscode/launch.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Docker: Python - Django",
            "type": "docker",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
            "python": {
                "pathMappings": [
                    {
                        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                        "remoteRoot": "/app"
                    }
                ],
                "projectType": "django"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

.vscode/tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "docker-build",
            "label": "docker-build",
            "platform": "python",
            "dockerBuild": {
                "tag": "dockerdebugging:latest",
                "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
                "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "pull": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "docker-run",
            "label": "docker-run: debug",
            "dependsOn": [
                "docker-build"
            ],
            "python": {
                "args": [
                    "runserver",
                    "0.0.0.0:8000",
                    "--nothreading",
                    "--noreload"
                ],
                "file": "manage.py"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

EXPOSE 8000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install pip requirements
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "helloworld.wsgi"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
# To ensure app dependencies are ported from your virtual environment/host machine into your container, run 'pip freeze > requirements.txt' in the terminal to overwrite this file
django==3.0.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

---

- VS Code Version: `1.47.1`
- Python Extension Version: `v2020.7.94776`

Comment: What is the computer system you are using? Is the same problem after reloading?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04, no luck after reloading. I just checked, and VS Code does successfull create a docker container, but can't connect anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue were missing packages. Docker usually works fine, I haven't had any issues before at all.

I originally installed docker like described in the official documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

But after I tried installing the `docker.io` package, debugging worked fine in VS Code:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea of debugging in vs code is to:

- use debugpy to launch your code with a port, say 5678
- in vscode to 'Remote Attach' to that process.

I may be wrong but what i can see from your code, you didn't attach to your process.

I wrote the way I did [here](https://miaoz2001.medium.com/debug-django-in-a-docker-compose-container-with-vs-code-88598dfc8be3), I use docker-compose and docker. My way is different with yours but you will get the idea...:)

Answer (score 1):

There's no errors compared to the vscode tutorial in your project. Cause the error is timeout waiting for luncher to connect, try restart docker service and reload your window in vscode.

Comment: I restarted docker, reloaded vscode, no success. I also restarted my machine (Ubuntu 18.04), no success as well. VSCode is creating a working container btw.

Comment: That's weired cause i've tried this tutorial, the same error, but after i restart docker,and it's running, the error disappeared.

Comment: I found the solution (see below), but because I can't give my bounty to myself, you can have it ;-)

Comment: so the question is missing pakages, got it, and thanks for your bounty~

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clue and a workaround:

The instructions I followed had me open VS code inside my ubuntu WLS2 instance. Note: my app is just a generic python app, not django.

[image: VS code on WSL]

If I click this and change it to open as a windows folder, then fun debug, everything suddenly works for me. (It spins up the docker and connects to it with debug, does breakpoints etc.)

[image: VS code native windows]

I think what is happening for me is that "sometimes" docker is starting the container/app on its own WSL instance and my ubuntu instance cannot route to it for the debug.

[image]

I say sometimes, because sometimes it works. I think it might be related to which application (docker, ubuntu, vscode) I start first when I boot my machine.
I've messed with the docker, resources, WSL integration settings, the windows firewall, and restarted various things.

I'm sure a proper fix is not that complicated, however running VS code in native windows is enough of a fix for me. I don't see why the added complexity of starting the VS code session inside WSL is actually necessary.